# How to detect when a network share is disable

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm building app which store information about network resources (shares) . I need to detect situation when administrator press stop sharing in Share and Storage Management Panel. How can I do that ? I read about WMI but I can't find solution.

Answer (score 0):

To check connection:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

[Microsoft MSDN Documentation: NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx)

To check any CHANGES:

[Microsoft MSDN Documentation: NetworkChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx)

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged 
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged
```